# Calling and returning a batch file to/from a for loop

Tags: batch-file

Searched out...cannot get this batch file to work the way I want it to.  The basic idea is I am using a for loop to grab values out of a text file, call another batch file to run a job with the value from the text file.  There is a sequence of jobs, and only the first one is running.  I cannot get the loop to continue with the next value from the text file.  Code below.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
@echo on
SET JOBNAME="JOBNAME"
SET STEPNAME=%%i

for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in (TEXTFILE.txt) do call :process %%i
:process
set STEPNAME=%1
CALL BAT2.bat "STEPNAME"
goto :EOF
```

BAT2

```
@echo on
SET JOBNAME="JOBNAME"
SET STEPNAME=%STEPNAME%

:S1
CALL RUNOTHERBATCH.BAT %JOBNAME% %STEPNAME%  > %JOBNAME%
%STEPNAME%.LOG
quit
```

Comment: you need `exit /b 0` or `goto :eof` before `:process` subroutine...

Comment: and probably this `%JOBNAME% %STEPNAME%  > %JOBNAME%` should be `%JOBNAME% %STEPNAME%  >> %JOBNAME%`

Comment: Thanks, I tried both changes unsuccessfully.  For some reason the loop is not continuing after the return of BAT2.  I will continue researching.

Comment: My apologies...I figured it out.  The third batch being called(RUNOTHERBATCH.BAT) had an exit in it.  Once I removed that it worked.  Thanks for your help.